# How to get last inserted id in SQLite with C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite

To get last inserted id or rowid from SQLite with C#, I tried that code and lastID is always returned 0. How can I fix this?

```
int lastID;
con.Open();
SQLiteCommand cmdekle = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO kullanicilar(adisoyadi, ilkendeks, sonendeks, kullanim, tutar, aciklama, odemetablo) VALUES(@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7)", con);
SQLiteCommand cmdSonID = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT last_insert_rowid();",con);
cmdekle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtadsoyad.Text);
cmdekle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", txtilkendeks.Text);
cmdekle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", txtsonendeks.Text);
cmdekle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", lblkullanim.Text);
cmdekle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", lbltutar.Text);
cmdekle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", txtbabaadi.Text);
cmdekle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", "Ödendi");
cmdekle.ExecuteNonQuery();
lastID=cmdSonID.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
long lastID;
con.Open();

using (var cmdekle = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO kullanicilar(adisoyadi, ...) VALUES(@p1, ...)", con))
using (var cmdSonID = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT last_insert_rowid();", con))
{
    cmdekle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtadsoyad.Text);
    ...

    int rowsAffected = cmdekle.ExecuteNonQuery();
    // check rowsAffected here

    lastID = (long)cmdSonID.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteScalar`is probably wath you need.

```
int lastID;
con.Open();
SQLiteCommand cmdekle = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO kullanicilar(adisoyadi, ilkendeks, sonendeks, kullanim, tutar, aciklama, odemetablo) VALUES(@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7)", con);

cmdekle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtadsoyad.Text);
cmdekle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", txtilkendeks.Text);
cmdekle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", txtsonendeks.Text);
cmdekle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", lblkullanim.Text);
cmdekle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", lbltutar.Text);
cmdekle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", txtbabaadi.Text);
cmdekle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", "Ödendi");

lastID=cmdekle.ExecuteScalar();
con.Close();
```

Comment: lastID is int, ExecuteScalar turns an object. If I convert it with lastID = Convert.ToInt32(cmdekle.ExecuteScalar()); I get always 0